# node.js numeric with decimal and roundings in knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, bigdecimal

In my postgres table I have a field which is type `numeric (30,16)` where I store numbers with many decimals. I need to compute these numbers.

I am using `knex` and by default it returns these values as `String` so in order to have as number, I've tried:

```
var types = require('pg').types
types.setTypeParser(1700, 'text', parseFloat);
```

However this still doesn't work right, for instance from `488.1456218300001000` and I substract `300` I can obtain something like `188.1456218300001500`.

What do I need to do in node.js to properly handle operations without any rounding errors?

Comment: Use something like [`bigdecimal`](https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering has nothing to do with knex or Postgres, it's just the way JavaScript's numbers work – their precision is not high enough to handle that many decimal digits.

You can find more info on this in [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript).

As suggested in the comments, if you really need higher precision, you can use a library like [big.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-js).

You can see how it works in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/stpodz8x/), look at this code example:

```
const Big = require('big.js');    

const a = 400.12345678901234567890;
console.log(a - 300); // 100.12345678901232 :-(

const b = new Big('400.12345678901234567890');
console.log(b.minus(300).toString()); // 100.1234567890123456789 :-)
```